# "Encoding" When Opening Up Saves Microsoft SQL File

Tags: sql-server

Fairly new to SQL, but saved a huge query and when I try to open it's asking me for "encoding".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2aYi.png)

I chose auto-detect as default but it just opens up a new query with a few random symbols when my query was hundreds of lines long.

Any idea how to get it back or what option to choose here? Is there a chance I saved over the file by mistake?

Comment: Open your `.sql` file with notepad. This will show if the file contains any data. Hundreds of lines should also make the size of your file multiple kilobytes. File size of 0 or 1 kb are a bad sign...

Answer (score 0):

On SSMS, select Tools/Options then expand (Text Editor), add the extension (sql) and map it to (SQL Query Editor).

[image]

This solution works if you are working with ASCII characters.